# $\sigma$-algebra on the parts of a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I was trying to find an example of a $\sigma$-algebra defined on a set which is itself a $\sigma$-algebra.
So, start with $X$ a set, and define $B$ a sigma algebra on $P(X)$ (with a mesure $\mu$).
Now, considering $B$ as a set, is it possible (does it show up in any literature) to define another $\sigma$-algebra on $P(B)$ with a new measure $\nu$ ?

If so, can you point out any literature on the subject or a construction of a sort?

Edit(16/01): I might have not been very clear here. A small example of what i was looking for:

A =  {1}

B = {$\emptyset$, {1}}

C = {$\emptyset$ , {$\emptyset$, {1}} , {$\emptyset$} ,{{1}} }

So as B is a trivial $\sigma$-algebra on A i can put a measure there and...

Now as C = $P(B)$ , same thing and i can put a measure there.

The thing was having "levels" of $\sigma$-algebras where one was defined on the parts o the previous one (not on the original set and not contained in the next but belonging to the next).

So i guess this would be an example but i was looking for something more "not trivial".

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#%CF%83-algebras_generated_by_families_of_sets), if that is what you are looking for. But in general, it is always possible to define a $\sigma$-algebra on any set.

Comment: Moreover, you can put trivial (discrete or indiscrete) sigma-algebra's on any set.

Comment: Marginally related: [Is the Hausdorff metric on sub-$\sigma$-fields separable?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/79869/15780)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sigma$-algebras and measures are different objects and they do not depend on each other. There are easy examples of $\sigma$-algebras that are defined on a set which is already a $\sigma$-algebra. For example, one can take the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ or $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{R})$ and the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$. Clearly, $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{R})$. Moreover, it is also true that $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$. Now, in general, you can define different measures on different $\sigma$-algebras too. A nice example is  this: take (again) $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}), \lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Then, we can define a measure $\mu$ on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ as:
$$ \mu(E) := \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{E}e^{-\frac{(t-a)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}d\lambda$$
where $\sigma > 0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$. This measure is called *Gaussian* with mean $a$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$. This is a probability measure on $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$, that is, it satisfies $\mu(\mathbb{R}) = 1$. You can create other measures by setting $\mu = \int f d\lambda$, for some nonnegative function $f$.

As a final comment, I should stress that defining different measures to different $\sigma$-algebras (one being 'inside' the another) is possible but you should ask yourself what is your purpose on doing that, once the measure on the 'big' $\sigma$-algebra restricted to the 'small' $\sigma$-algebra is not, in general, equivalent to the measure defined on the 'small' $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 0):

I will elaborate on my comment. Given any set of sets $B$ you can define the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains $B$ (and denote it by $\sigma(B)$) by the following
$$
\sigma(B)=\bigcap \{ \mathcal A | \mathcal A \text{ is a } \sigma \text{-algebra containing }B \}
$$

For any such set $B$ it is clear that the above intersection is non-empty since the power set of $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $B$.

Now if $B$ is itself a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\sigma(B)=B$, since the above intersection includes $B$, and all other $\sigma$-algebra must be bigger if they include $B$